# app id in slrequest

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Is it mandatory to use `app Id` while integrating with Facebook using SLRequest actually I don't have the `App id`,so is it possible to integrate Facebook using SLRequest without using `app id` as i dont have a registered itunes account?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
    ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSString *key = @"987654"; 
    NSDictionary *dictFB = //use ACAccountStore to help create your dictionary
   [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB
   completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
   if (granted) {
       NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
       //it will always be the last object with SSO
       self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
     } 
     else {
       //Fail gracefully...
       NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);
     }
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the appId means the `Facebook Client Id`. In [Facebook developer account](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) , you will get the `App ID/API Key`, where you would have created your application.

Comment: sorry i mean to say iphone App Store id

Comment: If u don't have your app in iTunes Store, justin Facebook's developer site while adding your app for native iOS, put 0 in app store ID.

Comment: No. It doesn't require iPhone App store Id. Go to the link , i provided and you need to create the application there to integrate facebook in your application.and there you will get the "App ID/API Key" to put it in your code.

Comment: iPhone app store ID: is not compulsary field. If you don't write anything , it will automatically take "0" as value.

Comment: If my answer helped you , then you can upvote it. And if it was the correct solution then accept the answer.